# Masonry with Wordpress galleries produces messed up layout on each refresh

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, jquery-masonry

I am trying to implement masonry to wordpress default gallery. I modified the `gallery_shrotcode()` to adjust the image sizes and to add the masonry class and attributes to the gallery div. Also I changed the `<style>` a bit

Here is the updated code:

```
function rf_gallery($output, $attr) {
$post = get_post();

static $instance = 0;
$instance++;

if ( ! empty( $attr['ids'] ) ) {
    // 'ids' is explicitly ordered, unless you specify otherwise.
    if ( empty( $attr['orderby'] ) )
        $attr['orderby'] = 'post__in';
    $attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
}

// Allow plugins/themes to override the default gallery template.
//$output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
//if ( $output != '' )
//    return $output;

// We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
    $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
    if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
        unset( $attr['orderby'] );
}

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
    'id'         => $post ? $post->ID : 0,
    'itemtag'    => 'dl',
    'icontag'    => 'dt',
    'captiontag' => 'dd',
    'columns'    => 3,
    'size'       => 'thumbnail',
    'include'    => '',
    'exclude'    => ''
), $attr, 'gallery'));

$id = intval($id);
if ( 'RAND' == $order )
    $orderby = 'none';

if ( !empty($include) ) {
    $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

    $attachments = array();
    foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
        $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
    }
} elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
} else {
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
}

if ( empty($attachments) )
    return '';

if ( is_feed() ) {
    $output = "\n";
    foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
        $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
    return $output;
}

$itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
$captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
$icontag = tag_escape($icontag);
$valid_tags = wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' );
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $itemtag ] ) )
    $itemtag = 'dl';
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $captiontag ] ) )
    $captiontag = 'dd';
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $icontag ] ) )
    $icontag = 'dt';

$columns = intval($columns);
$itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
$float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

$selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

$gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
    $gallery_style = "
    <style type='text/css'>
        #{$selector} {
            margin: auto;
        }
        #{$selector} .gallery-item {
            float: {$float};
            text-align: center;

        }
        #{$selector} img {

        }
        #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
        }
        /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
    </style>";
$size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
$gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} js-masonry' data-masonry-options='{ \"columnWidth\": 200, \"itemSelector\": \".gallery-item\" }'>";
$output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

$i = 0;
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
    if ( ! empty( $attr['link'] ) && 'file' === $attr['link'] )
        $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, array(300,600), false, false );
    elseif ( ! empty( $attr['link'] ) && 'none' === $attr['link'] )
        $image_output = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, array(300,600), false );
    else
        $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, array(300,600), true, false );

    $image_meta  = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );

    $orientation = '';
    if ( isset( $image_meta['height'], $image_meta['width'] ) )
        $orientation = ( $image_meta['height'] > $image_meta['width'] ) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';

    $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
    $output .= "
        <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon {$orientation}'>
            $image_output
        </{$icontag}>";
    //if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
    //    $output .= "
    //        <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
    //        " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
    //        </{$captiontag}>";
    //}
    $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
    if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
        $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
}

$output .= "
        <br style='clear: both;' />
    </div>\n";

return $output;
}
add_filter("post_gallery", "rf_gallery",10,2);
```

This code makes the layout completely messed up, and which is strange, it changes when browser reloads. More precisely the top positioning in inline style changes with each load to produce the three different layouts.

Here are the images of two layouts that come up:
[image: No1]

[image: No2]

[image: No3]

The last image is the correct layout.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to edit the gallery shortcode at all, that's really messy, why not simply use the existing classes?

```
var container = document.querySelector('.gallery');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.gallery-item'
});
```

Comment: I had to edit it for some other reasons as well... but see my answer below, i called it too soon :) but thanks anyway, here s an accept for you

Comment: I saw your answer but it would be stupid to edit the shortcode function if it wasn't needed, that's why I added this answer. Didn't know about those "other reasons" of course.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the order of calling scripts, the html was loaded before the script, answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849296/masonry-js-overlapping-items) resolved it for me.